# Prove that the set $[0,1]\setminus E$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, ergodic-theory

Let $E$ be the set of all $x \in [0,1]$ with the following property:

If $0.x_1x_2x_3...$ is a decimal expansion of $x$, then for each integer $k \geq 1$, the string $x_1x_2x_3...x_k$ appears infinitely often in the sequence $x_1x_2x_3...$ of the decimal expansion of $x$.

Prove that the set $[0,1]\setminus E$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

Now I know that if I fix a word $w=x_1x_2x_3...x_k$ of length $k$, $w\in\  \{0,1\}^k$; the frequency of $x$ appearing in the decimal expansion for almost every $x\in \{\frac{p}{10^n}| 0<p\leq 10^n;n\geq 1\}$ is $\frac{1}{10^k}$ then measure of $E$ would be $\sum_\limits{k=1}^\infty \frac {1}{10^k}=1 $. So, I am done right?

Comment: I don't understand your entire argument, but I am pretty sure that geometric series actually evaluate to one ninth. I am not sure that it makes a difference to your argument, but maybe it does!

Comment: The sum you have to get E assumes that the sets for each k are disjoint.  This is completely wrong.  For example, many of the strings for set k appear among the strings for set k+1 and also contain many of the strings for k-1.   In any case what you want to prove that if you define E for a specific k, E has measure 1.  To prove it look at the complement of E and show that it has measure 0.

Comment: In your attempt, you define $x$ as a rational number. What does it mean for $x$ to occur in a decimal expansion? What do you mean with frequency? How do you convert this into an argument about measure? Why you defined $w$ and never used it again? It's completely unclear to me.